# use xcode to instrument/profile third-party app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode-instruments

Is it possible to use Xcode Instruments to profile a third-party app? Right now, whenever I trying to profile any third-party app installed on device, I got error saying

'Target failed to run: Remote exception encountered: failed to get task for pid '

Is there any settings that need to be configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple documentation: For your protection, the instrument does not allow you to process any application that is not code-signed with your provisioning profile. This includes any copy that has been downloaded from the iTunes App Store.

Answer (score -1):

### UPDATE

As of more recent versions of iOS, you can only attach the profiler to your own developer-signed apps.

### ORIGINAL

Using Xcode 4.4.1 and my iPad 3 running iOS 5.1.1, I'm able to use the Core Animation and Time Profiler instruments on third-party apps.  I tried it with Twitter and Minecraft PE.

The profiles are rather useless since I don't have symbols for the apps.  I just get a lot of addresses in hex.  And Instruments won't even show me the disassembly of the apps.  I believe this is because iOS, for security, doesn't allow Instruments (or `gdb` or `lldb`) to look at the address space of apps installed from the App Store.

Comment: I am using Xcode 4.3.3 and my iPod running iOS 5.1.1. For whatever app/process/target that I tried to instrument against, the app will get launched and them immediately shut down. Did you have any special settings applied?

Comment: What instruments are you trying to use?

Comment: The memory allocation one, also tried the ones that you mentioned above - Core Animation and Time Profiler, all didn't work.